# Как iOS клиент-приложение получает доступ к сайту?

Tags: ios, сервер

Я так понимаю это обычный ajax-запрос на сервер? Тогда в каком формате приложение получает ответ от сервера? HTML, или какой-нибудь JSON?

Comment: Какое приложение? Какой сайт? В общем случае - через API, а значит JSON(XML). В более простых случаях css-верстка просто подгоняется под iУстройства, а сам сайт отображается через обычный браузер, встроенный в приложение.

Comment: API именно, про это хотел спросить. CSS и браузер в приложении это чушь. JSON значит. Можно по-подробрнее приминительно к клиент-приложениям iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну что можно сказать, чаще всего используется JSON request который непосредсвенно посылается из приложения. Потом приходит ответ от сервера, который вы собственно...скажем так парсите ответ обычно приходит в виде NSArray из которого вы и дергаете собственно ту информацию которая вам не обходима.

array of data = (
{

artistId = 367695209;

```
    artistName = "Funzio, Inc";
   artistViewUrl = "http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/funzio-inc/id367695209?uo=4";
    artworkUrl100 = "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/069/Purple/c7/5a/72/mzl.eiqzdszk.png"; 
    artworkUrl512 = "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/069/Purple/c7/5a/72/mzl.eiqzdszk.png"; 
   artworkUrl60 = "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/096/Purple/db/41/b5/mzi.qveqacpo.png"; 
    averageUserRating = "4.5"; 
    averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion = "4.5";
    bundleId = "com.funzio.modernwar";
    contentAdvisoryRating = "12+"; 
    currency = USD;
```

...}

Вот так выглядит JSON ответ от AppStore когда используется JSON. Почитать о JSON можно [тут](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c)
скачать фрэймворк вот [здесь](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) и еще немного чтива [есть тут](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/). Еще можно использовать NSXMLParser но он больше подходит, как ясно видно из названия больше для парсинга XML файлов, вся информация есть в [документации](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

З.Ы. Будут вопросы пишите.

Comment: Вместо  NSXMLParser я бы порекомендовал TBXML. Он гораздо проще в использовании, да и иногда быстрее.

Comment: Хммм интересно про TBXML парсер слышал но не когда не использовал, гуление рассказало о том что TBXML быстрее почти в два раза, памяти использует почти столько же сколько и NSXMLParser а во всем остальном почти идентичны ну кроме того что у них разные лицензии)
http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project  Стоит почитать на досуге.